# Weak measurement interaction Hamiltonian

Tags: quantum-measurements

I'm studying weak measurement and I would like to ask about the interaction Hamiltonian required for weak measurement.

The interaction unitary operator of weak measurement is defind as $\hat{U} = e^\hat{-iH} = e^{-ig\hat{\Pi}_s\hat{Y}_p}$ where $g$ is the interaction strength, $\hat{\Pi}_s$ is the projection operator on the system $s$, and $\hat{Y}_p$ is the pauli $\hat{Y}$ operator on the pointer $p$.

My questions is as follows:

Should the pointer operator always be the Pauli $\hat{Y}$ operator? Can't it be Pauli $\hat{X}$ operator or others?

Answer (score 0):

As far as the $U$ is a unitary operator, it is fine.  Consider this Hamiltonian of the form $H = g * (p \otimes x)$, $px$ is well known that it is Hermitian.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. By the way, what if the system operator $\Pi$ would be non-Hermitian?

Comment: @Alex I don't know what happens when we have non-Hermitian operator as system. But I hope this paper which I have not read gives you some answer: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1204.3296.pdf

Comment: Ok, I will read that paper. If we have a non-Hermitian operator in the system and a Hermitian operator in the pointer, do we need to call the entire operator as non-Hermitian?

Comment: @Alex Its trivially true, take $H^{\dagger} \neq H$